# C++ casting derived class to base type and back to derived

Tags: c++

I have a legacy class A which I want to extend (add another variable) but since this code is already in production adding a variable to a user facing class will break the binary compatibility. I tried using some casting to make it work but I ran into some issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A {
    public:
    int a;
    A() {
        cout<<"A Constructed"<<endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout<<"A Destructed"<<endl;
    }

};

class B : public A {
    public:
    int b;
    B() {
        cout<<"B Constructed"<<endl;
        b = 10;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B obj1;
    A obj2 = obj1;
    cout << "value is " << ((B*)&obj2)->b << endl;
}
```

I am expecting the value to be 10 since I set it in B's constructor but in practice I get 0. Is there a way to fix this to  get 10.

```
Output:-
./a.out
A Constructed
B Constructed
value is 0
A Destructed
A Destructed
```

Comment: The assignment slices the object  and  only the A part is copied.

Comment: `((B*)&obj2)->b` is UB. `obj2` is of type `A` and only `A`. Note that `&obj1 != &obj2`. When you try the given code you trigger UB because this cast is not valid (`obj2` has nothing to do with `B` class) and when you try to access `->b` you are potentially accessing memory which you don't really have.

Answer (score 3):

The initialization

```
B obj1;
A obj2 = obj1;
```

… copy constructs `obj2`, with a reference to `B` object passed to that constructor. Inside the constructor it's treated as (only) an `A` object. This is called **slicing**.

If the `A` objects are treated as value objects throughout the code, then you can't add state directly in them unless you can modify class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this line

```
A obj2 = obj1;
```

to be

```
A &obj2 = obj1;
```

because with your original code you call default copy constructor `A::A(const A& other)`